# $||x||^2/||A^{-1}||\leq x^TAx$ for positive definite symmetric matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, matrix-norms

I am trying to prove the inequality on Page 605 of Nocedal and Wright (Numerical Optimization);

$$\sigma_n(A)||x||^2 = ||x||^2/||A^{-1}||\leq x^TAx \leq ||A|| ||x||^2 = \sigma_1(A) ||x||^2$$

where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $\sigma_n(A)$ is the $nth$ singular value of $A$ and $\sigma_1(A)$ is the first singular value of $A$.

I have been able to prove every part of the inequality except for;

$$||x||^2/||A^{-1}||\leq x^TAx$$

If someone could provide a proof or a reference to a book that proves this it would be greatly appreciated.

Below are the details of the proofs of the other parts of the inequality;

First here is the proof of $x^TAx\leq ||x||^2 \cdot ||A||$;

$$\begin{aligned} x^TAx &= ||x|| \cdot ||Ax|| \cos (\theta) \\ &= ||x||^2 \cdot \frac{||Ax||}{||x||} \cos(\theta)\\ &\leq ||x||^2 \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||} \quad \quad \cos(\theta)\geq 0 \text{ since } x^TAx \geq 0\\ &= ||x||^2 \cdot ||A|| \end{aligned}$$

and also here is the proof of $$||x||^2/||A^{-1}||\leq ||A|| \cdot ||x||^2$$;

$$\begin{aligned}||x||^2/||A||^{-1} &=||x||^2 \min_{y \neq 0} \frac{||y||}{||A^{-1}y||} \\ &= ||x||^2 \min_{y \neq 0} \frac{||AA^{-1}y||}{||A^{-1}y||} \\ & \leq ||x||^2 \min_{y \neq 0} \frac{||A|| \cdot ||A^{-1}y||}{||A^{-1}y||} \\ &= ||x||^2 ||A|| \end{aligned}$$

Comment: It should follow directly from the fact that the minimum of Rayleigh quotient is the smallest eigenvalue and your matrix is symmetric psd so the singular values are just the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is symmetric positive definite, we can write $A = \sum_k \sigma_k v_k v_k^T$, and we can assume the $\sigma_k$ are ordered.

It is straightforward to check by multiplying that $A^{-1} = \sum_k {1 \over \sigma_k} v_k v_k^T$, and so $\|A^{-1}\| = {1 \over \sigma_n}$.

Then $x^TAx = \sum_k \sigma_k ( v_k^T x)^2$ and so
$\sigma_n \sum_k ( v_k^T x)^2 \le x^T Ax \le \sigma_1 \sum_k ( v_k^T x)^2$.

Since the $v_k$ are orthonormal, $\sum_k ( v_k^T x)^2 = \|x\|^2$.